# How to strip or escape html tags when saving a curl_exec() output to xml file

Tags: php, html, curl, joomla, google-calendar-api

I am importing some events from my Google calendar and I am doing this:

```
$ch = curl_init("my_google_calendar_url");
$fp = fopen("cal.xml", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch)
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting all the data dumped in XML file but along with the data all the html tags are also dumped in output which in turn is splitting output, e.g.

New HolidayWhen: Fri 21 Dec 2012 13:00 to 14:00&nbsp;
    IST<br>

```
&lt;br&gt;Where: Aus
&lt;br&gt;Event Status: confirmed</summary><content type='html'>When: Fri 21 Dec 2012 13:00 to 14:00 
IST&lt;br /&gt;

&lt;br /&gt;Where: Aus
&lt;br /&gt;Event Status: confirmed
&lt;br /&gt;Event Description: It&amp;#39;s going to be awesome.</content>
```

This is a small piece of what I am getting in my xml file. I want to strip all the html tags like "&lt" etc. so that it'll be easy to extract xml data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've tried to do it for you but you've made a pretty good mess with the HTML part. Since you have the original code, I suggest you edit the question and give it a proper format.

Comment: Yes @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I did what you asked. I would really appreciate a quick help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the CURLOPT_FILE option and use `$output = curl_exec($ch);`
You can then `$output = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($output));` and `fwrite($fp, $output);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but xml which is getting created have no tags at all. so now if I want to extract some fields how to do that? my whole and soul purpose for dumping data into xml was to make extraction easy using xml tags

Comment: In that case use `$output = html_entity_decode($output)` instead.

Comment: Hello When I use this i still can't remove &#39; which comes in place of ' i.e. an apostrophe

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is treated as data in the XML so:

1. parse the XML with an XML parser
2. fetch the HTML from the resulting DOM
3. [parse the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) with an HTML parser
4. extract whatever data you need from it